# Remove task from to do list + localstorage

Tags: local-storage

I have a to do list where I can remove an item by just clicking on it. I want to make sure that it vanishes from localstorage aswell, what should I put in "WHAT HERE?"

```
function removeMessage(e) {
    //e.target.remove();
    var parentNode = e.target.parentNode;
    parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
    localStorage.removeItem(WHAT HERE?);

}
```